# Issue with using a value in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP populated table from Mysql and I am using JQuery to listen if a button is clicked and if clicked it will grab notes on the associated name that they clicked.  It all works wonderful, there is just one problem.  Sometimes when you click it and the dialog(JQuery UI) window opens, there in the text area there is nothing.  If you are to click it again it will pop back up.  So it seems sometimes, maybe the value is getting thrown out?  I am not to sure and could use a hand.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        notes_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");
      run();
    });

});
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    
    showUrlInDialog(url);
    sendUserfNotes();
    
    
}
    function showUrlInDialog(url)
    {
      var tag = $("#dialog-container");
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
    function sendUserfNotes()
    {
        
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text()
            
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#notes_msg').text(response.the_notes)
        }
    });
    
    }
    function getNewnotes(){
        new_notes = $('#notes_msg').val();
        update(new_notes);  
    }
    // if user updates notes
    function update(new_notes)
    {
    
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/updateNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),
            'newNotes': new_notes   
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Notes Updated.");
            var i;
             $("#dialog-container").effect( 'fade', 500 );
            
            i = setInterval(function(){
             $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
            clearInterval(i);
            }, 500);
            
            }
    });
        
    }
    /******is user closes notes ******/
    function closeNotes()
    {
        var i;
         $("#dialog-container").effect( 'fade', 500 );
        
        i = setInterval(function(){
         $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
        clearInterval(i);
        }, 500);

    }
```

Let me know if you need anything else!

UPDATE:

The basic layout is

```
<div>
   <div>
     other stuff...

     the table
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would probably help the community if you posted your HTML or an example of what is happening using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Just a tip: `var i = setInterval(function(){ $("#dialog-container").dialog("close"); clearInterval(i); }, 500);` is the same as `setTimeout(function(){ $("#dialog-container").dialog("close"); }, 500)`

Comment: Could be a php error / problem, have you checked the error log on the server to see if there is anything there?

Comment: @rubeninfante there is tons of HTML

Comment: I believe James is on the mark.

Comment: @jeroen I don't believe so.

Comment: Is `#notes_msg` located in `#dialog-container`?

Comment: Yes the dialog opens the file that has the #notes_msg div in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `#notes_msg` is located in `#dialog-container`, you would have to make sure that the actions happen in the correct order.

The best way to do that, is to wait for both ajax calls to finish and continue then. You can do that using the promises / jqXHR objects that the ajax calls return, see [this section of the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

You code would look something like (you'd have to test it...):

```
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    var tag = $("#dialog-container");

    var promise1 = showUrlInDialog(url);
    var promise2 = sendUserfNotes();

    $.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(data1, data2) {
      // do something with the data returned from both functions:
      // check to see what data1 and data2 contain, possibly the content is found
      // in data1[2].responseText and data2[2].responseText

      // stuff from first ajax call
      tag.html(data1).dialog({
          width: '100%',
          modal: true
        }).dialog('open');

      // stuff from second ajax call, will not fail because we just added the correct html
       $('#notes_msg').text(data2.the_notes)
    });
}
```

The functions you are calling, should just return the result of the ajax call and do not do anything else:

```
function showUrlInDialog(url)
{
  return $.ajax({
    url: url
  });
}
function sendUserfNotes()
{
  return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
    data: {
        'nameNotes': notes_name.text()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How would I get the data into the function created in run?

Comment: Like is there something I can do that would say ...when showurl() is done than run senduserf...?

Comment: @David Biga The data from both ajax calls is available in what I have called `data1` and `data2`. And you don't want to run one after the other, it will be faster if you run both at the same time and simply wait until both are done before you show your dialog / add the html.

Comment: you don't understand I have to have the the showur...() one run first or if the other one were to complete first than nothing would display because the dialog never had the chance to open the file that contains the div that userf..() puts them in.

Comment: @David Biga I think I do understand. Note that none of the ajax calls in my answer modify the html: In the part where I wrote `// do something with the data returned from both functions` you need to do what you did before in 2 separate functions. I'll add some details...

Comment: @David Biga Check the update to see what is / should be happening.

Comment: just outputs success on the screen.

Comment: @David Biga Could be that the data returned is the complete response; if so, your data is found in `data1[2].responseText` and `data2[2].responseText`, just do a `console.log(data1, data2);` to make sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24401/discussion-between-david-biga-and-jeroen)

Comment: @David Biga No, I've got to go but the data is there, just do a `console.log` to see how you can access it.

Comment: All it tells me is success?

Comment: I did and that is what it says

Comment: I needed to do `$('#notes_msg').text(data2[0].the_notes)`  But i still have that anoyying message on the top left of screen that says success and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: @David Biga Comment out stuff until you know what is causing it exactly, then someone here can probably help you out.

Comment: tag.html(data1).dialog({
          width: '100%',
          modal: true
        }).dialog('open');

Comment: that is causing it when It opens the success displays

Comment: @David Biga Maybe `data1` is more than just your html and you only need part of it, like `data1[0]` as with the other variable. That would seem logical as the structure of both returned variables would be the same.

Comment: how can I see what is in each area in data without using console?

Comment: @David Biga You'd have to write a recursive function to loop through all properties, I would use the console... But if the data of your second function is stored in `data2[0]`, the data from the first function would be stored in `data1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from this, especially without the mark up, but both showUrlInDialog and sendUserfNotes are asynchronous actions. If showUrlInDialog finished after sendUserfNotes, then showUrlInDialog overwrites the contents of the dialog container with the data returned. This may or may not overwrite what sendUserfNotes put inside #notes_msg - depending on how the markup is laid out. If that is the case, then it would explains why the notes sometimes do not appear, seemingly randomly. It's a race condition.

Comment: I think your right, I need to make sure showUr...() first and than the other function

Comment: How do I do this...set a timer?

Comment: The easiest way to handle this would be to use callbacks. You can pass a function callback into showUrlInDialog. When showUrlInDialog is done, it calls your callback which in turn calls sendUserfNotes. That way the correct order is guaranteed to always be maintained.

Comment: Or, of course, just call sendUserfNotes() after the ajax request is complete in ShowUrlInDialog() - crushedGrass's answer.

Comment: I am having an issue with it displaying "succes"?

Comment: It works it just display success on corner of my screen every time

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can chain your ajax calls to keep sendUserOfNotes() from completing before ShowUrlInDialog(). Try using .ajaxComplete()

[jQuery.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Another ajax chaining technique you can use is to put the next call in the return of the first. The following snippet should get you on track:

```
function ShowUrlInDialog(url){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        tag.html(data).dialog({width: '100%',modal: true}).dialog('open');
        sendUserOfNotes();
    });
}

function sendUserOfNotes(){
    $.post('/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',{'nameNotes': notes_name.text()},function(response){
        $('#notes_msg').text(response.the_notes)
    },"json");
}
```

James has it right. ShowUrlInDialog() sets the dialog's html and sendUserOfNotes() changes an element's content within the dialog. Everytime sendUserOfNotes() comes back first ShowUrlInDialog() wipes out the notes. The promise example by jeroen should work too.

Comment: [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) says that the returned arguments are: [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ]

Comment: How do I get rid of the "success"  I am doing the guys above and it's working but success gets display on my page every time?

Comment: Most likely there is something in your code that is displaying the "success" value. Without seeing your implementation of the code it is hard to tell.